# Power states notifications in a Linux daemon

Tags: daemon, power-management

I have a Linux daemon and I want to be notified about the standard power states changes: sleep/resume, hibernate.
Right now I'm using pm-utils hooks, but I wonder if there is something similar to udev (by registering you can receive notifications about devices: add/remove/change/move).
acpid seems to be designed to notify user-space programs of ACPI events. I don't know if it can be used for a daemon.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no uevent broadcaster which sends sleep/wakeup related event. But you can send a uevent by yourself writing a driver which generates and sends one as soon as receiving `PM_SUSPEND_PREPARE`/`PM_POST_SUSPEND`. To do this, you should implement a notification block which receives PM_* notification and register it to the PM notifier chain using `register_pm_notifier(&your_notification_block)`. It means that you can write a translator driver which translates `PM_*` notification to a uevent.

But, when the system is going to sleep, **the kernel freezes all processes** prior to suspending. It means, although your daemon receives the uevent, there will be no time to do something you want.